# Invoke-command error when install Citrix VDA

Tags: powershell, citrix

I'm looking to install the Citrix VDA remotely. I ran this same command on the app server and it installed like I would expect. But now when I try to install it remotely with the invoke-command I get an error.

```
Invoke-Command -computer appserver.domain.com -scriptblock {start-process -FilePath "C:\XenDesktop 7.15\x64\XenDesktop Setup\XenDesktopVDASetup.exe" -ArgumentList "/noreboot /quiet /components VDA,plugins /masterimage /baseimage /enable_remote_assistance /enable_hdx_ports /optimize /controllers "ddc.domain.com""}

A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'ddc.domain.com'.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
+ PSComputerName        : appserver.domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either put dcc.domain.com in single quotes: 'ddc.domain.com' or fix those double quotes. To use double quotes in a double quoted string, you'll need to double them up:

```
-ArgumentList "/noreboot /quiet /components VDA,plugins /masterimage /baseimage /enable_remote_assistance /enable_hdx_ports /optimize /controllers ""ddc.domain.com"""
```

Comment: Thats what I thought at first but it didnt fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
-ArgumentList '/noreboot /quiet /components VDA,plugins /masterimage /baseimage /enable_remote_assistance /enable_hdx_ports /optimize /controllers "ddc.domain.com"'
```